GDAL.jni error on JENKINS Maven Build
When building our application in JENKINS Pipeline, it is failing with the error,
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V
at org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister(Native Method)
at org.gdal.gdal.gdal.AllRegister(gdal.java:595)

I have the GDAL dependency in our application POM.
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

This error is thrown due to below block,
static {
    gdal.AllRegister();
    ogr.RegisterAll();
}

Please help to fix this issue.
